# Android converting sequence of images to video generating "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't call getPixels() on a recycled bitmap" error

Tags: android, video, android-bitmap

Hi i am creating an android app that captures the sequence of screenshot and then converts it to the video. I don't have any problem on capturing screenshots. I am saving these screenshots in a Bitmap array. While converting the Bitmap images to video am getting the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't call getPixels() on a recycled bitmap` error.

Here is my code

```
public void convertToVideo(){
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/a.mp4");
    SequenceEncoder encoder;
    try {
        encoder = new SequenceEncoder(file);
        for (int i = 0; i < savedImagesPaths.size(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapScreenShots.get(i);
            pic = BitmapUtil.fromBitmap(bitmap);
            for(int j=0;j<24;j++){
                encoder.encodeNativeFrame(pic);
            }
        }

        encoder.finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error Creating Video - "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But when i am trying to take image from external path and decoded as a bitmap, the video is created.

```
String photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Pictures/1419673564585.jpg";
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
```

i don't want to take images from external path, i want to save images in bitmap array and use it.

How can i resolve this?

Here is my logcat

```
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211): Process: com.example.drawingfun, PID: 15211
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't call getPixels() on a recycled bitmap
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkRecycled(Bitmap.java:352)
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixels(Bitmap.java:1342)
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at org.jcodec.scale.BitmapUtil.fromBitmap(BitmapUtil.java:31)
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at org.jcodec.scale.BitmapUtil.fromBitmap(BitmapUtil.java:23)
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at com.example.drawingfun.MainActivity.convertToVideo(MainActivity.java:295)
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at com.example.drawingfun.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:247)
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
01-20 14:52:02.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: When i am debugging it with Bitmap(Not array) also producing the same error. I think Just an Bitmap doesn't take much amount of memory.

Comment: The framework is a constraint (memory) and , to work with that you may be better off using file system (external storage) for your bitmap collection. Ffmpeg for example makes video from sequence of photos , so u could compress your bitmaps then call ffmpeg on the photos

Comment: Yes, But Ffmpeg is an alternative solution for creating sequence of images to video, I am very closer in this to get output, i can get output by using external images and decoded it as a bitmap, but my problem is when using the image by taking the screenshot at runtime and save it as a bitmap, it is generating the exception.

Comment: And one more thing i have to mention is that i am using jcodec to convert video. http://jcodec.org/